# Adding multiple Middlewares to Laravel routes using LaravelCollective/Annotations

Tags: laravel, routes, annotations, laravelcollective

The current version of LaravelCollective Annotations doesn't give support for multiple annotations.

Answer (score 1):

As I request in this pull request:

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/annotations/pull/89

Just modify the file:
 vendor/laravelcollective/annotations/src/Routing/Annotations/Annotations/Middleware.php

and add these lines to the method "modifyCollection" as showed bellow:

```
public function modifyCollection(EndpointCollection $endpoints, ReflectionClass $class)
{
    foreach ($endpoints as $endpoint) {
        foreach ((array) $this->value as $middleware) {

            //Fix start
            if($multipleMiddlewares = explode(',', $middleware)){
                $middleware = '';
                $nbMiddlewares = count($multipleMiddlewares)-1;
                for($i=0; $i<=$nbMiddlewares; ++$i) {
                    $middleware .= $i > 0 ? "'" : '';
                    $middleware .= str_replace(' ', '', $multipleMiddlewares[$i]);
                    $middleware .= $i < $nbMiddlewares  ? "', " : '';
                }
            }
            //End of fix

            $endpoint->classMiddleware[] = [
                'name' => $middleware, 'only' => (array) $this->only, 'except' => (array) $this->except,
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, just add the annotations separated by coma like this:

```
/**
 * @Middleware("web, auth, role:super-admin|admin")
 */
```